# What is "airspace underlying a Class B airspace area designated for an airport"?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, airspeed, class-b-airspace

For the purposes of airspeed restrictions within airspace, the FAA regulations list the following area description (emphasis mine):

[14 CFR 91.117 (C)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c5da463aeef18b9cee56fe93e6e7b124&mc=true&node=se14.2.91_1117&rgn=div8)

> No person may operate an aircraft in **the airspace underlying a Class B airspace area designated for an airport** [...] at an indicated airspeed of more than 200 knots (230 mph).

Should we understand the described airspace to be any and all airspace underlying a Class B where that specific Class B is designated for an airport? Or, should we understand the described airspace to be any and all airspace designated for an airport (Class C, D, or E) which is underlying a Class B?

Are there letters of interpretation or other regulations which clarify the grammatical ambiguity of this regulation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is [a legal interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2015/duncan-afs-1_4%20-%20(2015)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf) on this:

> [...] under  the  express  language  of  the  regulation,  aircraft 
>   operating  in  the  airspace  underlying  Class  B  airspace -
>   irrespective  of  whether  the  underlying  airspace  is  controlled 
>   or  uncontrolled - may  not  exceed  the  200-knot  speed  limitation

So it is indeed any and all airspace underlying class B.

And note the exception to the rule:

> We  note  § 
>   91.117  (d)  does  provide  that,  if  the  minimum  safe  airspeed  for  any  particular  operation  is  greater  than  the  maximum 
>   speed  prescribed  in  § 
>   91.117,  then  an  aircraft  may  be  operated  at  that  minimum  speed.

Comment: Therefore, the retention of the phrase, "designated for an airport" is superfluous and is to blame for the ambiguity of the regulation.

Comment: Indeed.  "Designated for an airport" does appear in some of the descriptive language in the paragraph introducing class B airspace in FAA Order 7400.11C, but there was no reason to put it into that FAR.  Likewise with some other regs-- see for example https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65697/a-question-about-far-91-225e2-pertains-to-ads-b-out-requirement-and-aircr .  However there are some other regs where the inclusion of the phrase "designated for an airport" arguably functions specifically to exclude E4 (Class-E-to-surface "extension") airspace and thus is not superfluous.

Comment: If we were including parenthesis is in algebra equations, the phrase would like like this:  (the airspace underlying (a Class B airspace area designated for an airport))   .  "Designated for an airport" modifies "a Class B airspace area" rather than modifying "the airspace underlying".  And yes it appears to be completely superfluous here.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Pondlife's answer, the reason for this rule is that many VFR aircraft will try to fly under Class B airspace to avoid dealing with ATC so the airspace underneath the shelves of class B can be congested.  Therefore the FAA put this lower speed limit in place to allow for better VFR separation of aircraft under Class B airspace.